# Why wont this left join work?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am having trouble with this block of code. The error is near  LIKE. This is the code...

```
try {
    $st = $db->query('SELECT', "SELECT a.`fast_cash` as `fast`, a.`urgent_cash` as `urgent`, b.`store_name` as `store` FROM `Locations` a LEFT JOIN `loan_balances` b ON b.`store_name` LIKE '%' + a.`nick` + '%'", 'array'); 
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: `+` is the string concatenation operator in SQL Server.  You appear to be using MySQL so use the function `concat()`.

Comment: what common field makes a relation between a and b? The LIKE statement is more of a WHERE after you specify what you're joining on

Comment: you need to specify WHERE, on LEFT JOIN after ON you specify which column is related to which column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `on` clause you are looking for is:

```
ON b.`store_name` LIKE concat('%', a.`nick`, '%')
```

No `where` clause is needed for this query.